# Active Record count multiple joined tables in one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, count

Assume I have the following models:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :staffs
  has_many :items
end

class Staff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

Now for a particular shop, I want to get its number of staffs and number of items in one query. Is it possible?

I have tried the following query but the result is multiplied by each other:

```
@shop = Shop.joins(:items, :staffs).select('COUNT(items.id) AS items_count', 'COUNT(staffs.id) AS staffs_count').find(params[:id])
# => @shop.items_count = 30, @ship.staffs_count = 30
# Where the correct result should be 5 and 6
```

Comment: It seems you're not accessing a particular shop, that's way you get the count of every shop in your DB. Or was it a typo?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thanks! I missed `.find(id)` at the end of the call chain.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly a `joins` approach doesn't work for this case. What you can use is a subquery to get every items and/or staffs from the current shop row:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM items  WHERE shop_id = t1.id) items_count,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM staffs WHERE shop_id = t1.id) staffs_count
FROM shops t1
WHERE t1.id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

The ActiveRecord way would be using a RAW SQL statement for the `select` parameter plus using `from`:

```
Shop
  .select('(SELECT count(*) FROM items  WHERE shop_id = t1.id) items_count, 
           (SELECT count(*) FROM staffs WHERE shop_id = t1.id) staffs_count')
  .from(Shop.where(id: 1), :t1)
```